# name 'mydb' is not defined

Tags: python, mysql-connector

I'd like to access mydb variable on line 15, but it can¨t be seen. Even though I would go for Global variable, it still stays the same.

Code:

```
import mysql.connector

def connect():
    try:
        mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host='localhost',
        user='root',
        password='12345',
        database="Food"
        )   
    except:
        print("Possibly wrong PWD")


mycursor = mydb.cursor()
```

Error:

NameError: name 'mydb' is not defined

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `mydb` is inside a try/exception . if your `try` runs to a exception, the `mydb` variable is not going to be created and in the result you get the "not defined" error

Comment: `mydb` is a _local_ variable inside the `connect()` function.  It is not visible at the outer main scope where the `mycursor` line is.  And you never call `connect()` anyway!

Comment: @JohnGordon: Indented as written, they wouldn't see that message, because `connect` is never called, they just tried to load from a non-existent variable (even if `connect` *was* called, `mydb` wouldn't exist outside it, whether or not the attempt to connect succeeded).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you call a function? I see you defined it, but don't see where you call it. Try

```
import mysql.connector

def connect():
    try:
        return mysql.connector.connect(
        host='localhost',
        user='root',
        password='12345',
        database="Food"
        )   
    except:
        print("Possibly wrong PWD")

mydb = connect()
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. My problem was when I had the return in function that I wanted to do this:

mydb = connect().mydb - wanted to access mydb, but it was actually returned alread.

Thank you all!